# Сделать проверку в Scheduler (Spring Boot и Vaadin 14)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

У меня создан чат, и есть шедулер который каждую 1 секунду выводит непрочитанные смс. Так вот к шедулеру нужно написать вот такую проверку -

1) Запускается чат

2) Заходим под любым ником срабатывает функция Last (в базе данных хранится 26 смс тоесть айди последнего смс 26, плюс он там выводит последние 10 сообщений так как функция Last работает)

3) После срабатывает функция Unread он знает что айди последнего сообщения 26, и получается он возвращает empty, так как новых сообщений нет.

4)Прошло уже 20 секунд, шедулер снова вызывает Unread где айди последнего смс 26, но снова возвращается empty так как новых сообщений нет.

5)После через 30 секунд кто то написал 2 сообщения, и значит в базе уже 28 смс, Unread прошлый раз запомнил, что айди последнего сообщения 26, тем самым он нам выводит 27-28 смс

6) Потом через минуту кто то написал еще 3 смс, и значит в базе уже 31 смс, Unread прошлый раз запомнил, что айди последнего сообщения 28, тем самым он нам выводит 29-31 смс

Шедулер у меня написан в классе

```
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {
    private final MessagesInfoManager messagesInfoManager;
    private final RestService restService;
    private String username;
    private TextField textField;
    private static Message messageLast;



    @Autowired
    public MainView(RestService restService) {
        this.messagesInfoManager = MessageConfigurator.getInstance().getChatMessagesInfoManager();
        addClassName("main-view");
        setSizeFull();
        setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);

        H1 header = new H1("Vaadin Chat");
        header.getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

        add(header);

        askUsername();
        this.restService = restService;
    }

    private void askUsername() {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        TextField usernameField = new TextField();
        Button startButton = new Button("Start chat");

        layout.add(usernameField, startButton);

        startButton.addClickListener(click -> {
            username = usernameField.getValue();
            remove(layout);
            showChat(username);
        });

        add(layout);
    }

    private void showChat(String username) {
        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<Message> lasts = restService.getLast();
        for (Message message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.getFromV() + ": " + message.getMessageV()));
        }

        messageLast = lasts.get(lasts.size() - 1);

        add(messageList, createInputLayout(username, messageList));
        expand(messageList);
    }

    private Component createInputLayout(String username, MessageList messageList) {
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.setWidth("100%");

        TextField messageField = new TextField();
        messageField.addKeyDownListener(Key.ENTER, keyDownEvent -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        Button sendButton = new Button("Send");
        sendButton.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.LUMO_PRIMARY);

        layout.add(messageField, sendButton);
        layout.expand(messageField);

        messageField.addFocusListener(event -> {
            for (Message message : messagesInfoManager.getMessagesByUI(getUI())) {
                if (!message.getFromV().equals(username)) {
                    message.setUnread(false);
                    this.restService.updateMessage(message.getId(), message);
                }
            }
        });

        sendButton.addClickListener(click -> sender(messageField, messageList));
        messageField.focus();

        return layout;
    }

    private void sender(TextField textField, MessageList messageList) {
        Message message = new Message(username, textField.getValue());
        restService.saveMessage(message);
        messageLast = message;
        this.textField = textField;
        messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, message, this));
        textField.clear();
        textField.focus();
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
    public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {

        MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

        List<LinkedHashMap> lasts = restService.getUnreadMessages(messageLast.getId());

        for (LinkedHashMap message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.get("fromV") + ": " + message.get("messageV")));
        }



    }

}
```

Comment: вы можете в строке `List<LinkedHashMap> lasts = restService.getUnreadMessages(messageLast.getId());` получать не `List<LinkedHashMap>`  а `List<Message>` ? Можно поправить  этот метод в сервисе?

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось у самого, Создал новый метод -он берет последнее сообщение которое определяется в других методах. Если на вход приходит пустой обьект он заново делает запрос в бд и забирает айди последнего сообщения

```
public long getIdLastMessage (Message messageLast) {
    if(messageLast == null) {
    List<Message> lastMessages = restService.getLast();
    return lastMessages.get(lastMessages.size()).getId();
    }
    else {
    return messageLast.getId();
    }
    }

        @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
        public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {

            MessageList messageList = new MessageList();

            List<LinkedHashMap> lasts = restService.getUnreadMessages(getIdLastMessage(this.messageLast));

            for (LinkedHashMap message : lasts) {
            messageList.add(new Paragraph(message.get("fromv") + ": " + message.get("messagev")));
    }

            messagesInfoManager.updateMessageUIInfo(new MessageInfo(messageList, messageLast, this));


    }
        }
```